# How to get Extent Report work with Junit

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, junit

Im having troubles configure Extent Report with junit-java.
The documentation only covers testNG.

Can anyone please explaine how to implement it right?
copy his code?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).